# How to quantify convergence in a stochastic experiment?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

My son told me about an experiment they had in biology classes to introduce the dominance in traits and evolution.

- you start with 6 marbles of 6 different colors
- for each color, you randomly pick a number $n$ between 1 and 6 and add to an empty bowl $n$ marbles of that color (you have a large reserve of marbles of all the colors)
- you end up with 6 to 36 marbles of various colors in the bowl
- you then randomly pick 6 marbles from the bowl, empty the bowl, and this is the starting point of the next iteration (second bullet above)

Note: each of the 6 marbles is independent and the number which is picked for each of them adds that number of marbles of that color to the bowl. This means that if you have (I will just use three marbles here, the experiment is on 6 of them) *red* *red* *yellow*, you would pick (and put in the bowl) $n=\textrm{rand}(6)$ *red* marbles, then $k=\textrm{rand}(6)$ *red* marbles, and then $r=\textrm{rand}(6)$ *yellow* ones, ending with $n+k+r$ marbles in the bowl.

The conclusion after several experiments was that after about 7 generations you end up with 6 marbles of one single color. I believe the idea of the experiment is to show that a random process can lead to the preference of one trait over the others (but the interpretation does not matter for the question here)

He was interested in writing some code to simulate that, so I did my homework and wrote it in advance so that I can be the super dad who knows the answers to everything. I ended up with the following distribution of the number of generations needed for a set of six marbles of the same color after 100,000 iterations:

[image]

My concerns/questions are the following:

- is there a certainty that the experiment is convergent = that the iterations with the 6 marbles eventually finishes with a set of 6 marbles of one color? (intuitively and with some hand waving I think so)
- is there a way to quantify the distribution above, that it to show by calculation that for instance the average number of generations for 6 marbles will be 5.58 (this is an example - based on what I see in the distribution)
- or alternatively: is there a function (distribution) which corresponds to the experiment? (from which the average and other interesting numbers can be derived)

Comment: I don't totally understand the fourth and fifth bullets. Are you randomly drawing 6 marbles out and then using them to add more marbles into the bowl? What happens when fewer than the selected number of marbles of a given color still exist? Can the marbles you used for color selection go back into the bowl, or do they just do that by default?

Comment: Also "end up with a single color" is that a single color in the bowl itself or that your next draw from the bowl only has one color in it?

Comment: @Ian: sorry, I failed to add that the marbles are picked from the bowl. Sorry for that. I updated my question with the details. Please let me know if this is clear now.

Comment: Oh, now it is almost clear, you randomly select a group to "reproduce" and all the others "die". So now the only unclear thing is what you do when you are asked to put, say, 8 red marbles into the bowl.

Comment: @Ian: this time it is me who does not understand :) Say I have 3 marbles instead of 6 (less typing) and start with red blue yellow . For red I pick a number between 1 and 3 (say, 2) and put 2 red marbles in the empty bowl. Then I move to blue and pick a nr between 1 and 3, say 1. 1 blue goes into the bowl (which now has 3 red 1 blue). Then the third marble (yellow) - I pick a number between 1 and 3 (say, 3) and therefore put 3 yellows in the bowl.

Comment: (cont'd from previous comment) I shake the bowl and pick a random 3 marbles, say yellow blue yellow. I empty the bowl. And start again: yellow marble, pick a number (say 1), put 1 yellow in the bowl, then blue marble, pick a number (say 1), put 1 blue in the bowl and finally third marble (yellow), pick a number (say 2) and put 2 yellows in the bowl. I have 1 yellow + 1 blue + 2 yellow = 4 marbles, I pick 3 of them randomly and start again.

Comment: @Ian: your point *you randomly select a group to "reproduce" and all the others "die"* is a good and interesting explanation. I am not sure about whether the experiment is a correct model for such reproduction (I do not think but I need to think longer on that -- and in any case this does not change the mathematical question )

Comment: Yeah, now the only thing I still do not understand is if you have red red (and then four non-red colors) and you get 2 6s, how many reds wind up in the bowl? 6 or 12?

Comment: 12. You treat each marble independently, no matter its color. You just look at the color, pick a number, add that number of marbles of the color you look at and then move to the next marble (which may or may not be the same color as the one before). Each marble participates to the bowl independently. In your case it is "red marble, get a 6, add 6 red marbles, nex ton eis red, get a number (6) , add 6 red marbles, next ...This is BTW the essence of the "Note" in my question, I will therefore rewrite it to make it more clear.

Comment: OK. So now the way to set everything up with the fewest possible number of states is to use the most recent draw from the bowl rather than the bowl contents as the state. This still results in a rather large number of states, 462 to be exact (the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \dots x_6=6$). Now the absorbing states are the ones with only one color represented, and the process can reach an absorbing state starting from any other state.

Comment: Thus an absorbing state will be reached with probability 1 (this is a theorem for finite state Markov chains), in other words eventually you will draw just six marbles all of the same color (after which you will continue to do that forever). I can in principle tell you how to set up a system of 462 linear equations in 462 unknowns to find the average absorption time. Besides that I think it is difficult to figure out the distribution of the absorption time here. (Even setting up that matrix to find the average is a bit painful...)

Comment: @Ian: thank you , this confirms my suspicion about the convergence of the exercise. In that case would you know whether the iteration is distributed in a specific manner?

Comment: I doubt it has any standard form, but you might be able to fit the Monte Carlo data you have to some standard distribution...at a glance it looks kind of like a log-normal distribution.